# How to fetch public folder .json file into react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am trying to calculate the array and show the number on the dashboard. I tried to `fetch('data/users.json)` but got an error that shows 0.
Need to calculate the id from two JSON files located at public folder inside data folder, you can see on the code below.

```
import React from 'react'
import '../Navbar/navbar.css'
import '../Dashboard/dashboard.css'
// import UserList from "./data/users.json"

const Dashboard = () => {

    
    return (
        <div>
            <main>
                <h1 className= "heading">Welcome to Dashboard</h1>
                    {/* <p> User data list : {Object.keys(UserData).length}</p>
                    <p>Suscriber list: {Object.keys(Suscriber).length}</p> */}
                <p>
                    Lorem
                    ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat accusantium
                    rerum dolorem odio amet id blanditiis nobis incidunt consequuntur
                    molestiae doloribus corrupti quidem dolor ex, assumenda beatae dolore?
                    Voluptatem, ab?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                </p>

                <div className="users_view">
                    <div className="flexs">
                        <div className="total_users">
                            <h1>Total Users: {Object.keys(fetch('data/users.json')).length} </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flexs">
                        <div className="total_users">
                            <h1>Subscribed user: {Object.keys(fetch('data/subscriptions.json')).length}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
            
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Below image is of directories:

[image]

Anyone help me to fetch those 2 JSON data and calculate the array number to display on the dashboard.
Below images show the output:
[image]

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The part about not posting pictures of text.

Comment: please paste the code in the question

Comment: And read an introductory guide to `fetch`. It doesn't return synchronously parsed JSON.

Comment: okay, thanks! I was trying to place the directories image but I placed the whole SS. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I'd advice to import a json file:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [users,setUsers] = React.useState([{}])
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('data/users.json').then((res)=>res.json()).then((data)=>{
      setUsers(data)
     })
     
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Users:{users.length}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is the sample `users.json` file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name 2"
  }
]
```

this is the structure of the main directory:
[image]
Here is the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-chihiro-fwiml)

Comment: `users.json`  file is placed on a public folder inside the data folder.
I tried this but doesn't work

Comment: @RakeshShrestha please check my update. If you find it working as intended, you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to import your JSON:

```
import data from 'data/users.json'
```

Then make a length of the data

```
Object.keys(data).length
```

or use JSON.parse

Comment: `users.json`  file is placed on a public folder inside the data folder.
I tried this but doesn't work

Comment: Ah indeed, it should be placed in the `src/` it should work

Comment: Yes, it works when I placed it in the `src` folder. But I need to fetch it from the `public` folder. Anyway, I got my answer thanks for answering.